# How can I check if the connected wifi is 2.4Ghz through Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, wifi, ssid

Is there a way to check if the wifi that the user is connected to is 2.4Ghz or not programmatically through Swift? Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: [Current Wifi Check for 2.4Ghz](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/120987)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks for the reply! However the post you linked mentions in the replies that as of 2 years ago, there is no way to check if the wifi is 2.4 or 5 Ghz. I'd like to know if there are any other solutions to this problem?

Comment: @wepowf The last time I went hunting for this (last year), no (I think I poked Apple directly) - they don't like giving up WiFi information, although, I'd be very happy to be wrong

Comment: I don't have an answer, but every app I have used that you need to set a 2,4 Wifi, make the user responsible to pick the right one. So I would say is not possible